# Adb: loopback mount at startup

Tags: android, adb

I would like to use adb to mount a `.img` file as a loopback device on a non-rooted android phone. However I need this mount to persist on reboot… any clue how to do that? (I'm on Android 11)

**EDIT**

I thought that the mount command would just work… but turns out it's not the case:

```
$ mount DCIM/virtualfs test_mount/                                                                                                                                                              
mount: bad /etc/fstab: No such file or directory
```

See more details in this new question https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/249009/mount-a-loopback-device-from-sd-card-without-root

Comment: If the mount command works from within an app you could develop an app that starts automatically after reboot and mounts the image.

Comment: @Robert thanks, but seems like in fact the basic mount command is not even working. See more details here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/249009/mount-a-loopback-device-from-sd-card-without-root